# one menu bar hiding under another after minimizing

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I make two navbars but it doesnt work correctly. Do you have any advices ? It looks like this, but after minimizing I am missing HOME MIBs and LIBRARY tabs. I think that upper menu covers bottom menu.

[image]

I would like to be able to see all tabs after clicking on the menu button.

Here is my code
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>my site</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
   body {
  padding-top: 50px;
  }
  </style>
   </head>
   <body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation"> 
  
 <div class="navbar-header">
    <div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">LOGO</a></div>
  <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-target=".navbar-collapse" data-toggle="collapse">
  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
 </div>
 
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
   <li><a href="#">Friends</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
   <li class="dropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Account <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Stats</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
  </ul>
   
 </div>
</div>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation"> 
 <div class="navbar-header">
  <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-target=".navbar-collapse" data-toggle="collapse">
  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
 </div>
 
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li class="dropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">MIB's <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">my MIB's</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">my feedback's</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">my comment's</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>

 <li class="dropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Library <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Standard</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Random</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Custom</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>

 <li><a href="#">Badges</a></li>

 <li class="dropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Help <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>   

  </ul>
 
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: just remove position: fixed and it show up everything

Comment: Hello, after removing position fixed my menus are separated and they go with 2 menu buttons :( I would like to have only one menu button and not separated menu bars :)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>my site</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
   body {
  padding-top: 50px;
  }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 550px) {
   body {
 padding-top: 0px;
  }
    .navbar-fixed-top {position:static;}
 .navbar{margin-bottom:0;}
}
  </style>
   </head>
   <body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation"> 
  
 <div class="navbar-header">
    <div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">LOGO</a></div>
  <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-target=".navbar-collapse1" data-toggle="collapse">
  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
 </div>
 
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-collapse1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
   <li><a href="#">Friends</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
   <li class="dropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Account <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Stats</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
  </ul>
   
 </div>
</div>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation"> 
 <div class="navbar-header">
  <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-target=".navbar-collapse2" data-toggle="collapse">
  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
 </div>
 
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-collapse2">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li class="dropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">MIB's <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">my MIB's</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">my feedback's</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">my comment's</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>

 <li class="dropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Library <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Standard</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Random</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Custom</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>

 <li><a href="#">Badges</a></li>

 <li class="dropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Help <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>   

  </ul>
 
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Use this. it is working perfact

Comment: Hello, yes this is what I want to achieve but I don't want to have two menu buttons, only one, after minimizing and it shoul display all tabs :) Do you have any advice? :)

Comment: ok hide second navigation and move all option in first navigation in mobile view .